# Issue with plotting a contourplot using atan2

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, atan2

I am trying to plot a multiplication of Gaussians in polar coordinates, but I have an issue with the atan2 function of Python.

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xmin = -400
xmax = 400
ymin = -400
ymax = 400
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])

delta = 2
x = np.arange(xmin, xmax+delta, delta)
y = np.arange(ymin, ymax+delta, delta)

mu_rho = 173.528
mu_theta = np.pi/2
sigma_rho = 50
sigma_theta = np.pi/2

PS = [[0 for i in x] for j in y]

for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        theta = np.arctan2(y[j], x[i])
        rho = np.sqrt((x[i])**2 + (y[j])**2)

        PS[j][i] = math.exp(-((rho-mu_rho)**2)/(sigma_rho**2)) * math.exp(-((theta-mu_theta)**2)/(sigma_theta**2))

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

plt.contour(X,Y,PS)

plt.show()
```

but in the resulting plot no contours are plotted in the third quadrant (x < 0 and y < 0). I think this is because of an issue with the atan2 function, but I am not sure. Can someone explain to me why there is nothing in this third quadrant and how I could solve this? Thanks.

Picture of resulting contourplot:
[image: Picture of resulting contourplot]

Comment: `atan2` works just fine.  Your `PS` values are extremely low, almost zero in the third quadrant.  An alternative to show the data is `plt.scatter(X, Y, c=PS, cmap='inferno', norm=matplotlib.colors.LogNorm())` followed by `plt.colorbar()`. However, there is a large discontinuity between the second and the third quadrant.

Comment: There is no problem in arctan2. Maybe the implementation formula of PS is incorrect. Show the formula of PS you are implementing and the output plot that you are expecting

Comment: Thanks for the comments. You could be right in that the issue is not in the arctan function, but in the PS formula. The PS formula is a product of Gaussians, one around rho and one around theta in polar coordinates. I would expect the output plot to be symmetrical around the y-axis, meaning that the contour plot in the third quadrant should be the same as in the fourth quadrant. I can't figure out why the figure ends in a straight line towards the third quadrant.